# displaying multiples of same component using ngFor and @Input decorator in template

Tags: angular

I'm using ngFor loop in my outer component template to display multiples of an inner component via one-way binding and the @Input decorator.

NOTE: I am using naming substitutes for privacy reasons.

**Outer Template:**

```
<h1>Things</h1>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let obj of objects">
    <app-inner-component [object]="obj"></app-inner-component>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Outer TS code**

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  object = [
     new Object('firstObject'),
     new Object('secondObject')
  ];
...
```

**Object Model**

```
export class Object {
   private name: string;

   constructor(name: string) {
      this.name = name;
   }
}
```

**Inner Component Template**

```
<h2>{{this.name}}</h2>
```

**Inner Component TS Code**

```
export class InnerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() object: Object;
```

The rendered Outer template shows only one bulletpoints (no name display). When I comment out the HTML selector, `app-inner-component`, two bulletpoints are present.

I expect the Outer template as:

**Things**

**-firstObject**

**-secondObject**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing I can see is that the presense of `this` in the template `<h2>{{this.name}}</h2>`, it should not exist in the template.

Your template should be `<h2>{{object.name}}</h2>`

Comment: wow it worked. thank you! is `this` not a valid keyword for referencing the component instance?

Comment: yes, if the variable is `public` then you don't need the word `this` as it exists only inside the `ts/js` files